# Why is my custom cursor goes into the page background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-cursor

I already made a custom cursor, but the problem is when the `nav{position: fixed}` then the cursor goes into the background of the navbar. Even the same problem occurs with bootstrap-5 cards and as well as buttons. What is the problem? give me a relevant solution...

***index.html:***

```
<div class="cursor"></div>  
<div class="cursor2"></div>  

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light p-4 fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mb-5 px-3 support_return_payment_secure_container">

        <!-- bootstrap 5 card -->
        <div
            class="col-10 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xxl-2 d-flex justify-content-center support_return_payment_secure_card py-3 mx-1 my-1">
            <div class="support_return_payment_secure_icon_container">
                <div class=""><i class="fas fa-user-headset "></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</nav>
```

***style.css:***

```
.cursor {  
    width: 50px;  
    height: 50px;  
    border-radius: 100%;  
    border: 1px solid #0AD8C7;  
    transition: all 200ms ease-out;  
    position: fixed;  
    pointer-events: none;  
    left: 0;  
    top: 0;  
    transform: translate(calc(-50% + 15px), -50%);  
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 0.0625em 0.0625em, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 0.125em 0.5em, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset;
    animation: cursorAnim1 .5s infinite alternate;
}  
.cursor2 {  
    width: 20px;  
    height: 20px;  
    border-radius: 100%;  
    background-color: gainsboro;
    border: 1px solid #008F84;
    opacity: .3;  
    position: fixed;  
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
    pointer-events: none;  
    transition: width .3s, height .3s, opacity .3s; 
    animation: CursorAnim2 .5s infinite alternate;
}
```

***cursor.js:***

```
var cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');  
var cursorinner = document.querySelector('.cursor2');  
var a = document.querySelectorAll('a');  
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){  
    var x = e.clientX;  
    var y = e.clientY;  
    cursor.style.transform = `translate3d(calc(${e.clientX}px - 50%), calc(${e.clientY}px - 50%), 0)`  
});  
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){  
    var x = e.clientX;  
    var y = e.clientY;  
    cursorinner.style.left = x + 'px';  
    cursorinner.style.top = y + 'px';  
});
```

Comment: Simple. Make sure the cursor element is the very last element on the page, right before the `</body>`. Also give it a huge `z-index`, just in case any other elements in the same stacking context have non-auto `z-index` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting the huge z-index, the issues were solved...

```
.cursor{
    z-index: 2000;
}
.cursor2{
    z-index: 2000;
}
```